# Is crossover cable still needed?

Tags: cable

Do I still need a [crossover cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable) to connect two PC's directly? (NIC <-> NIC)?

If not, then why was this needed in the past, and when was it used for this? Specifically, when did crossover cables stop being needed to directly connect 2 PCs?

Comment: Note: Cross-over cables only applied to 10 and 100Mb Ethernet. Gigabit sends and receives on all 4 pairs at the same time.

Comment: Why is this off-topic?

Comment: @ChrisS, what you describe only applies to UTP cabling. Ethernet on fiber-optic cabling still requires a crossover cable between two like devices, even at gigabit speeds.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most (all?) current devices have implemented [ethernet auto mdix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_Dependent_Interface#Auto-MDIX). The answer is simple: You don't need such cable.

Comment: but from when? from 10 years ago?

Comment: @evachristine there is probably no border date..

Comment: Then I will say about ~2005... according to google searches..

Comment: @evachristine I remember having to use on in the 90s. I think by the early 2000s most devices were Auto MDI-X. Then 1GbE took over and made the whole thing moot.